# Why can I not create an instance of a class I have created, in the app/decorator folder for my rails project, in the console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, decorator

I have made a folder and file

```
decorators/my_model_decorator.rb
```

and in it created the class

```
require 'delegate'

class MyModelDecorator < SimpleDelegator
  attr_reader :my_model

  def initialize(my_model)
    @my_model = my_model
  end

  def containable
    ContainableDecorator.new(my_model.containable)
  end
end
```

But referring to it in the like this

```
instance_x = MyModel.new

decorated_my_model = MyModelDecorator.new(instance_x)
```

Throws this error

```
NameError (uninitialized constant MyModelDecorator)
```

(Weirdly, I am able to run the code in the browser and the error message does know about the decorator class and I can access its methods in the console on the browser.  )

Why am I getting this behaviour?  Do I need to do something to “initialize” the class I have created?

according to this [thought.co article](https://www.thoughtco.com/nameerror-uninitialized-2907928#:~:text=Ruby%20NameError%20Uninitialized%20Constant%20Causes,a%20regular%20NameError%20exception%20class.&text=You'll%20see%20this%20error,file%20to%20load%20the%20class.)

> "You'll see this error when the code refers to a class or module that
>   it can't find, often because the code doesn't include require, which
>   instructs the Ruby file to load the class."

I don't quite understand this. Are you supposed to tell Rails to require MyModleDecorator somewhere?  If so is there a particular place I am supposed to put this code?

Comment: Did you `reload!` or close and restart the console after creating the class?

Comment: I did try restarting the console

Comment: Try to add your folder to autoload paths in `config/application.rb`. `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'decorators')`

Comment: Yea @Yakov adding that configuration has worked.  Thanks.  I'm quite new to rails and programing.  I'm curious how routine having to add the configuration like this is.

Comment: It is quite common I reckon. Eventually, you can have `app/validators`, `app/serializers`, `app/anythingelse`, it might be difficult to predict what should be preloaded automatically.